# dart how to split string by regex like this?

Tags: dart

How to split:

```
String a = 'abc,Hello, 123,world';
a.split(RegExp(',[a-zA-Z]'));
```

as the following:

```
abc  
Hello, 123
world
```

But the code above will produce:

```
abc
ello, 123
orld
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [lookahead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Regular_expressions/Lookahead_assertion):

```
,(?=[a-zA-Z])
```